# Cloud Foundry can't auto create tables using Mysql

Tags: cloud-foundry

Solved

Found the problem, I had a schema defined in my java class

I have a cloud foundry app which uses a mysql data service.

It works great but I want to add another database table.

When I re-deploy to cloud foundry with the new entity class it does not create the table and the log has the following error

2012-08-12 20:42:23,699 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - CREATE command denied to user 'ulPKtgaPXgdtl'@'172.30.49.146' for table 'acl_class'

Comment: Hi, is this a Grails application?

Comment: found the problem, I had a schema defined in my java class

Answer (score 1):

Schema is created dynamically via the service. All you need to do is bind the application to the service and use the cloud namespace. As you mentioned above, removing the schema name from your configuration file will resolve the issue.